# Text in canvas Entry box inserted, but not visible

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code:

```
# Create entry box with initial text and color
username_entry = tk.Entry(canvas, width=37, fg=light_gray, font=font, bd=0, insertbackground=lighterish_gray) #border=.5,)
username_entry.insert(0, 'Username')
username_entry.configure({"background": lightish_gray})

# Define functions to handle focus and unfocus events
def on_entry_click1(event):
    if username_entry.get() == 'Username':
        username_entry.delete(0, "end") # Delete all the text in the entry
        username_entry.configure(fg=light_gray)

def on_entry_unfocus1(event):
    print("unfocused")
    print(f"inside the input box is '{username_entry.get()}', and the length of the string is {len(username_entry.get())}")
    if len(username_entry.get()) == 0:
        print("inserted")
        username_entry.configure(fg=lightish_gray)
        username_entry.insert(0, 'Username')
        print(f"Now, inside the username_entry is: {username_entry.get()}")

# Bind focus and unfocus events to entry box
username_entry.bind('<FocusIn>', on_entry_click1)
username_entry.bind('<FocusOut>', on_entry_unfocus1)

# Place entry box on canvas
canvas.create_window(280, 125, window=username_entry)

# Create entry box with initial text and color
password_entry = tk.Entry(canvas, width=37, fg=light_gray, font=font, bd=0, insertbackground=lighterish_gray) #border=.5,)
password_entry.insert(0, 'Password')
password_entry.configure({"background": lightish_gray})

# Define functions to handle focus and unfocus events
def on_entry_click2(event):
    if password_entry.get() == 'Password':
        password_entry.delete(0, "end") # Delete all the text in the entry
        password_entry.configure(fg=light_gray)

def on_entry_unfocus2(event):
    print("unfocused")
    print(f"inside the input box is '{password_entry.get()}', and the length of the string is {len(password_entry.get())}")
    if len(password_entry.get()) == 0:
        print("inserted")
        password_entry.configure(fg=lightish_gray)
        password_entry.insert(0, 'Password')
        print(f"Now, inside the password_entry is: {password_entry.get()}")

# Bind focus and unfocus events to entry box
password_entry.bind('<FocusIn>', on_entry_click2)
password_entry.bind('<FocusOut>', on_entry_unfocus2)

# Place entry box on canvas
canvas.create_window(280, 175, window=password_entry)
```

And I ran the code, and on unfocus, the Username, and Password, text is not re-inserted, although it says it is, it is not visible.

When I added the print statements, this was the result:

```
unfocused
inside the input box is '', and the length of the string is 0
inserted
Now, inside the username_entry is: Username
```

However it does say that inside the username_entry is the text "Username", it does not actually display it:

Comment: Perhaps the reason you can't see the text is that you've configured the Entry to display lightish_gray on lightish_gray?

Comment: Sorry, I am realizing that and not understanding how I could have missed that. Oops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, and I should have noticed, but I put the same color text on top of the same color Entry box.
My bad!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).